# php executing differently on browser or command line

Tags: centos, php-7, apache2.2

Good morning guys,
I just built a CentOS server with php 7.0.13 and apache 2.2 and the strangest thing is happening when testing it.
I had a curl script that works perfectly well through the command line but not when invoked through the browser, after investigating a bit, I realized that I can also not write to files if I do it through the browser, but I have no problem whatsoever doing it through the command line.

I assumed that the problem would be on two different php.ini files, but after verifying the phpinfo I realized that both the CL and the browser are loading the same, and all extensions seem to be loading correctly as well, by using get_current_user() I can also verify that the same user is executing both. I would assume the problem would be in apache, but I have no clue as to what could be causing it.

Can someone point out to possible avenues to solve the issue? I have no idea what to do from this point onwards.

Comment: through your terminal , often you are working with root -except you changed your user' , within your apache2 server you are working through normal privileged user , often called `www-data` user , often this will be solved by changing the dir permission. however, it will be better if you provided a full example of code.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, the code is indifferent here to be honest because either curl or fopen are failing but it was due to the different user executing the script.
get_current_user() gives the owner of the script, not the executer, To find out the user executing the script use: exec('whoami');

Answer (score 0):

As Hassan indicated the problem was with the user executing the script.

I commited an error thinking get_current_user() indicates the user executing the script, it does not, it indicates the file owner.

If you have a similar problem and need to figure who is executing the script use exec('whoami'); instead.

EDIT:Ok although that was one of the errors, the main error was on the fact that SELinux was activated, as soon as I deactivated the scripts started working perfectly.